# Build fail error

Tags: iphone, xcode, build-process, build-error

I am baffled about this error since **I installed xcode 4.2 from xcode 3.2 and switched back to xcode 3.2** Since then I am not able to build for device for any of my projects for any configurations.

The error shown is:

> CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.app cd
>   "/Users/macadmin/Documents/iPhoneProjectDocs/Madhup/Test/Test
>   Development/MyProject" setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>   /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Madhup (MW9495NA8W)"
>   "--resource-rules=/Users/macadmin/Documents/iPhoneProjectDocs/Madhup/Test/Test
>   Development/MyProject/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.app/ResourceRules.plist"
>   --entitlements "/Users/macadmin/Documents/iPhoneProjectDocs/Madhup/Test/Test
>   Development/MyProject/build/MyProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.build/MyProject.xcent"
>   "/Users/macadmin/Documents/iPhoneProjectDocs/Madhup/Test/Test
>   Development/MyProject/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.app"
>
> /Users/macadmin/Documents/iPhoneProjectDocs/Madhup/Test/Test
>   Development/MyProject/build/Debug-iphoneos/MyProject.app: object
>   file format invalid or unsuitable Command /usr/bin/codesign failed
>   with exit code 1

The things I have tried to get over this are:

- Completely removed all provisioning profiles and certificates and re-install them.
- Change configurations (Debug to some other)
- Completely uninstall and re-install xcode

Moreover if I try to build my project from some other systems with same provisioning profile, developer certificate and same build configuration I don't face any problem.

Please help me out as I am so frustrated and thinking of OS re-install :(

Comment: Maybe miss some framework link ?
I got problem is the same Xcode project can run in Xcode 4.2 Lion version but can't build in Xcode 4.2 Snow leopard version...

Comment: no solution found.. finally switched back to Xcode 4.2 :(

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify, you've removed xcode with...

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

Have you also cleaned the build (Product menu -> Clean)?  I know this sounds a bit of an obvious one - but lots of people forget to do it!